# Dropdownlist not loading after the first time Windows form

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/fo237nt0p0i8m50/AACk4T-NdZFvvxmkL_m8-rCpa?dl=0
this is an application i have made on windows form. The matter is in ucUsers user control ,the group combobox is loading initially after that even if i change the data from group.Even after loading the data it doesnt show the updated value. i have tried so many things but i cant find this ghostly problems solution.

```
private void ucUsers_LoadAsync(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dbEntities db = new dbEntities();
        ddlGrp.DataSource = db.usergroups.ToList();
        ddlGrp.ValueMember = "Id";
        ddlGrp.DisplayMember = "name";

        loadusers();
    }
```

this method is working in every other dropdowns. even its working in the groups page.IS there anyone who can help?

Comment: Adding a link to dropbox for US to search through YOUR code is not really helping. Add a more specific question to your problem or at least add more code to what is the problem.

Comment: First of all this method is not async. Second - it is better to use using for dbEntities - using(var db = new dbEntities()){ // your code}. At last - do you have any values in usergroups?

Comment: @Sasha i was trying async as a test but it didnt work and i forgot to change the name thats all. and i have tried using as well its not working either. while i save them from usergroups yes the value gets saved and comes in dropdown immediately there.but it doesnt load in user. it only shows the thing that was loaded first time.